# How to remove lights and show only pure texture color in blender?

Tags: texturing, lighting

In Godot game engine and also in old Blender you could view a model or an entire scene by just their texture colors without ambient lights or dynamic lights.

How do I do the same thing in Blender 3.4?

In old Blender it was enough to delete or hide the light source and the scene would only show the pure textures, but in the new Blender even without any lamp or light sources the model still tries to look "3D" and reflect light like it's plastic.

I don't like it, I know I can change it when I export it to the game engine but I don't like working with it looking like that in Blender.  :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the shading tab and connect the texture (image) directly to the Material Output with no shader (BSDF) in between. This will give a *Shadeless* output - the object does not receive any lighting or shadows:

[image: Shadeless]